# Object is mirrored at incorrect location

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

Having a spot of trouble, I'm new to blender, I've added mirrors to meshes fine no problems, but I'm now trying to mirror a mesh and its not mirroring where I want it to be, I need the mesh to be in the same location on the other side of the tank

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that you have set as the *Mirror Object* ('Cylinder') on the object you want to mirror ('Cylinder.010') is not at the centre of your tank, therefore, neither is the mirroring.

If you still want to use a *Mirror Object* then choose a different object to use as your *Mirror Object* (one that has it's origin at the centre of the tank).

For example, here I change the *Mirror Object* to be 'Cube.004' and the mirroring is correct:

[image]

Comment: This one solved the main issue and was the easiest solution greatly appreciated I had thought in order to mirror an object it had to be under the same name IE in this case I used Cylinder...

Thank you to both users who gave me advice here

Comment: What I would suggest is either not using *Mirror Object*s and just moving the origin as the other answer shows or making an *Empty* object at the centre of the tank that you can use for all of your mirror modifiers (which means you can move any of the objects and not worry that some other object is relying on them for mirroring).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the location of the mesh you are mirroring, you need to place it as shown below and it's mirror location will change as well:

[image]

You need to set the point of origin as well.
 To move the origin, typically one would use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  -> cursor to selected to snap the 3d cursor to a desired location and then you can move the origin with shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>  Or by pressing "origin" on the (T)ool panel.

Added gif showing all the steps:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: moving the mesh makes the mirror move closer rather than away, even when I place the mesh in the location I want it to be on the model it mirrors literally right next to the mesh...

I think it may have something to do with the point of origin, I cant move the Axis Cursor to be centered on the mesh, so I think that is causing some distance issues...

Sorry If I not explaining it correctly I'm new to it all.

Comment: @StandSure  Updated my answer to set the origin of the mesh properly :)

Comment: appreciated bud, I've done all of the above, point of origin is set, but the mirror won't mirror on the other side of the red line, the mirror only stays on the right hand side of the red line until I move the mesh miles over to the right

Comment: @StandSure could you upload your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2631" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2631/)

Comment: @StandSure answer edited with a gif showing the steps to solve your problem and updated .blend file provided. Let me know if this solved your problem, and if it did then please accept the answer :)

Comment: @Tak I think you should actually wait until the OP clarifies that this has solved the problem before suggesting they should accept.

Comment: @RayMairlot No worries, I've updated my comment :) thank you

Comment: @Tak  That's done it nice one and its greatly appreciated bud :)

Comment: @StandSure No worries, glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Snap cursor to center or object center then snap origin to cursor.