# Mirroring distance is wrong

Tags: modifiers, mirror-modifier

I am new to blender (modeling for 2 days)

I've been doing a kitchen by tutorial of Polygon Runaway, and have got a problem of mirroring a door

[image]

[image]

I've tried to move the 3D-cursor, origin(I read this article: [Object is mirrored at incorrect location](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/object-is-mirrored-at-incorrect-location)), but this didn't help.
P.S: You can see how it should work on 7:05 of this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AScTgh_V4Dw&t=675s)

I know that i set mirror object (you can see it on the screenshots), but it isn't the problem, i was just picking random objects hoping it will help me.

Comment: if you watch the tutorial closely you will see that he didn't enter a mirror object. But you did....(may not solve your problem, but you should always follow exactly the tutorial)

Comment: Yea, I forgot to clean mirror object before doing screenshots, I set it when I was trying to solve my problem( I just picked random objects hoping it will help me)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symmetrize option doesn't mirror bones on the axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194148/symmetrize-option-doesnt-mirror-bones-on-the-axis)

Answer (score 1):

You've set an object as *Mirror Object (Plane.003)*, so your object will mirror with this mirror object as center, not with its origin, it must be your problem here:

[image]

If you remove the *Mirror Object*, make sure that the origin is correctly placed because it will now be the mirror center, see where it is now:

[image]

Comment: Forgot to say, i've also changed the mirror objects, and it didn't help me too(

Comment: So maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: see my edit, the center of the mirror will be the object's origin, not the 3D cursor, the 3D cursor may be helpful to place the origin where you want though